# php-ml regression predicts weird values

Tags: php, machine-learning, regression, php-ml

My input values are 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and my output values are 1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4, ...
My code looks like this:

```
$reg = new LeastSquares();

$samples = array();
$targets = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
{  
  $samples[] = [$i];
  $targets[] = $i*$i;
}

$reg->train($samples, $targets);
  
echo $reg->predict([5])."\n";
echo $reg->predict([10])."\n";
```

I expect it to output roughly 25 and 100. But I get:

```
-1183.3333333333
-683.33333333333
```

I also tried to use SVR instead of LeastSquares but the values are strange too:

```
2498.23
2498.23
```

I am new to ML. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`LeastSquares`](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/regression/least-squares/) is for **linear** regression. How do you expect it to work here?

Comment: @Olivier I also tried [SVR](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/regression/svr/). How to fix it?

Comment: Do you know what SVR is?

Comment: @Olivier Not really. I thought AI is like a black box which is a neural network. You give it inputs and outputs and in this training proccess it learns. That is what I wanted to do. But now it seems I have to choose the right model based on my input data. That is new to me because I thought the neural network does everything by itself.

Comment: Least squares don't use a neural network. I'm not familiar with SVR but I highly doubt it uses a neural network.

Comment: And even for techniques based on neural networks: there are many different types of NN, and many possible configurations (number of neurons, number of layers, transfer function...). You need knowledge to design a good NN. It's not magical.

Comment: I think `PolynomialRegression` or `Multilayer Perceptron` is more suitable for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments `LeastSquares` is for fitting a linear model to your data (training examples).

Your data set (target = samples^2) is inherently non-linear. If you try to picture what happens when you fit the best possible (in a least square of residuals sense) line to a quadratic curve you get a negative y-intercept (a sketch of this below):

[image]

You've trained your linear model on data up to x=99, y=9801, which will mean you have a very large y-intercept. So down at x=5 or x=10 you end up with a large negative value as you've found.

If you use support vector regression with a degree-2 polynomial it will do a good job of capturing the pattern of your data:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Phpml\Regression\SVR;
use Phpml\SupportVectorMachine\Kernel;

$samples = array();
$targets = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{  
  $samples[] = [$i];
  $targets[] = $i*$i;
}

$reg = new SVR(Kernel::POLYNOMIAL, $degree = 2);
$reg->train($samples, $targets);

echo $reg->predict([5])."\n";
echo $reg->predict([10])."\n";
?>
```

Returns:

```
25.0995
100.098
```

From your response in the comments its clear that you're looking to apply a neural network so that you don't have to worry about what degree of model to fit to your data. A neural network with a single hidden layer can fit any continuous function arbitrarily well with enough hidden nodes, and enough training data.

Unfortunately php-ml doesn't seem to have a MLP (multilayer perceptron - another term for a neural network) for regression available out-of-the-box. I'm sure you could build one from appropriate layers but if your goal is to get up and running with training regression models quickly it might not be the best approach.